# How to read this txt and get all the lines with 'take'?

Tags: python, file

I want to get all the lines in the arcane script that has 'take', but I cannot do it with my code, can you show me how to do it? thanks!!!

```
x = open("Arcane.S01E01.Welcome.to.the.Playground.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.x264-TEPES.英文.txt")
for line in x:
    if not 'take' in line:
        continue
    print(line)
```

Sorry, I don't  know how to upload my txt here, so i can just show part of the script here. It is line by line in my txt file.

part of the script:

```
♪ Dear friend across the river ♪
♪ My hands are cold and bare ♪
♪ Dear friend across the river ♪
♪ I'll take what you can spare ♪
♪ I ask of you a penny ♪
♪ My fortune it will be ♪
♪ I ask you without envy ♪
♪ We raise no mighty towers ♪
♪ Our homes are built of stone ♪
♪ So come across the river ♪
We're almost there.
Aw, man.
Hey, Powder. Come take a look.
Whoa. It's nice getting above it all, huh?
One day, I'm gonna ride in one of those things.
And one day, I'm gonna shoot one of 'em down.
Vi, are, are you sure about this?
-Look, if we get caught, we're-- -We're not gonna get caught.
We'll be in and out before anyone notices.
All right, everybody, follow me. Just don't look down.
Couldn't we have at least just walked there?
Gotta stay out of sight for this one.
Called it. This is on you, Vi.
-I'll get her. -No.
Powder, look at me.
What did I tell you? That I'm ready.
That's right! So?
Thanks.
What if Vander finds out we're all the way up here?
Look around you. You think anyone topside's going hungry?
Besides, this is exactly the sort of job Vander would've pulled
when he was our age.
I'm going. Are you with me or not?
Vander's gonna kill us. Yeah, only if we screw up.
So don't screw up.
All clear.
Who locks their balcony?
```

expected output:

```
♪ I'll take what you can spare ♪
Hey, Powder. Come take a look.
```

Comment: include a bit of the text and include the word/criteria **take** too.

Comment: What does your code do currently?

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("Arcane.S01E01.Welcome.to.the.Playground.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.x264-TEPES.英文.txt", "r") as a_file:
  for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip().decode("utf-16")
    if 'take' in stripped_line :
      print(stripped_line)
```

Comment: it says:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: try other encodings

Comment: @jtop its because of ♪. try using `stripped_line = line.strip().decode("utf-16")`

Comment: While this definitely improves on OP's code (the `with` part definitely, not sure why you feel stripping is necessary here), please explain how this answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming that's how your file is originally formatted (**'\n'** present at the end of each line):

[file_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s411S.png)

- Then you can use **splitlines()**

  ```
   # Reading file and decoding it because of '♪'
   file_path_str = "Arcane.S01E01.Welcome.to.the.Playground.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.x264-TEPES.英文.txt"
   with open(file_path_str, "rb") as txt_file_obj:
       x_str = txt_file_obj.read().decode("UTF-8")

   # Getting the lines where 'take' is present
   for line_str in x_str.splitlines():
       if 'take' in line_str:
          print(line_str)
  ```
- Results:
  [results_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdJp0.png)

  - ♪ I'll **take** what you can spare

  - ♪ Hey, Powder. Come **take** a look.